# How to make redis work locally?

Tags: local, redis

I've got a redis db. Now I need to make it work locally. I mean I want it to be accessable on my local machine only. No requests over network. How can I do it?

I found redis.conf with the following content:

```
# If you want you can bind a single interface, if the bind option is not
# specified all the interfaces will listen for incoming connections.


bind 127.0.0.1
```

Row `bind 127.0.0.1` was commented before. I restarted redis using `service redis restart`, but I still able to read from redis over network.

Answer (score 1):

Set the config option "protected-mode" to "yes" and leave uncommented the "bind" option:

```
bind 127.0.0.1
rotected-mode yes
```

Then be sure your running `redis-server` instance is starting with the config you're modifying.
Stop the instance and run it manually with:

```
redis-server /path/to/your/redis.conf
```

Redis will run in foreground&verbose mode (showing a pretty ascii art).
Then check its binding address as usual:

```
# netstat -nap|egrep redis
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6379          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      30772/redis-server
```